# Will there be a noticable difference in sharpness and color between Nikon and Canon

Tags: lens, canon, nikon, sharpness

Hi I have a Nikon D750 with a 70-200mm f2.8 VRii lens and a 35mm f1.8G ED lens. I mostly shoot family portraits. I was thinking about switching to the Canon 5D Mark IV with a 24-70mm f/2.8L II USM Lens and a 70-200mm f/2.8L IS II USM Lens. Will there be a noticeable difference in image sharpness and color?

Comment: Could you explain *why* you're thinking of switching to what is a very similar setup?

Comment: Why should Vicky explain her motivation for thinking about switching?  It has no impact on the answer she's looking for.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th Because this feels like an XY problem. There might be a good reason for switching from full-frame Nikon to full-frame Canon, but that's a pretty rare thing for people to do, particularly if they're not already aware that the differences are minimal at best.

Comment: So a question about whether there is any "noticeable difference in sharpness" between four specific lenses, from two different manufacturers, is closed as a duplicate of a question that doesn't even include the words "sharp" or "sharpness".  Genius.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to notice any difference in sharpness. Your current lenses combination is better than 24-70mm for family photos. If you prefer the different color tone Of Canon, that is another story then.

Answer (score -1):

+1 for @user58923 answer. Adding words:  70mm can be a DX portrait lens, but it is too short for full frame. The 70-200 (at around 105 to 120 mm) is much better perspective for full frame portraits.  Meaning, you always want to stand back at 7 to 10 feet for proper facial perspective. This focal length forces that distance.  I don't see how you could be unhappy with the 70-200.

Color is determined by selecting proper white balance for the light, and by color profile choice.  Regardless of brand, DO NOT USE VIVID or LANDSCAPE for portraits.  :)  Try Neutral, Portrait, or even Standard.  And for the lights, get a white balance card.